# why access by ip is ok but domain fails?

Tags: python, django

I start a new Django APP on a server with public IP, then run it with command:

```
python manage.py runserver publicip:port
```

then I found when i access it with `http://publicip:port` it works fine.
but when I access it using the domain name (which is resolved to this ip), it fails,
and gives the blow errors:(https://dpaste.de/FIrk)

```
0 errors found
October 10, 2013 - 10:31:13
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'testsite.settings'
Development server is running at http://*.*.*.*:8709/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 189, in send_preamble
    self._write('HTTP/%s %s\r\n' % (self.http_version,self.status))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 389, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
  error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('58.33.144.118', 53268)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line     150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Can anyone give some suggestions to find out why, thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time, but i think i should write this down for others who has the same problem.

It is because the domain name is not BeiAn(备案) in China, and the ISP blocked access to this server.

Answer (score 4):

Run `runserver` with the domain name instead of the IP:

```
python manage.py foobar.com:8000
```

Remember that you [most definitely shouldn't use `runserver` in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Comment: run server with domain fails again.  This is just a test, my production env is using nginx/uwsgi but have the same problem. :(

Comment: any more suggestions?